# iOS Clang -std -stdlib options c++11 error

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, c++11, clang

I have an iOS project set up like this:

- I use XCode 6.1.1
- `clang -v` says `LLVM version 6.0`
- I use the flag `-miphoneos-version-min=6.1` (I don't set `-std` and `-stdlib`)

Everything's fine.

When I update to `-miphoneos-version-min=7.1` I have following errors in code includes the header new.h

Because it is a big project, I have created a new .h file that include new.
The problem is that the new header includes exception that includes `type_traits` header.  'type_traits' is a c++11 header.  Because I am not using C++11, this raises errors.

I don't want to activate c++11 now.

I tried `-miphoneos-version-min=7.1 -std=c++98 -stdlib=libc++` but whatever I try, I still have the new header leading to type_traits header leading to errors.

Any idea how can I build with `-miphoneos-version-min=7.1`? And why when I was with `-miphoneos-version-min=6.1` the include new.h was fine (and not including type_traits header)